# Python Pandas Panel Data - Filling missing values with information of the same observation from other periods

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, panel-data

I am working with a data set of panel data.
That is, I have observations of some units over many time periods.

For example:

```
dates = 3 * list(pd.date_range(start='1/31/2018', end='3/31/2018', freq="M"))
unit_id = ["id_1", "id_1", "id_1", "id_2", "id_2", "id_2", "id_3", "id_3", "id_3"]
locations = ["loc_1", "loc_1", np.nan, "loc_2", "loc_2", np.nan, "loc_3", "loc_3", np.nan]
var_1 = ["x1_t1", "x1_t2", "x1_t3", "x2_t1", "x2_t2", "x2_t3", "x3_t1", "x3_t2", "x3_t3"]
var_2 = ["z1_t1", "z1_t2", "z1_t3", "z2_t1", "z2_t2", "z2_t3", "z3_t1", "z3_t2", "z3_t3"]

_ = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "id": unit_id, "location": locations, "var_1": var_1, "var_2": var_2})
```

This gives me something like this:

|  | date | id | location | var_1 | var_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-01-31 | id_1 | loc_1 | x1_t1 | z1_t1 |
| 1 | 2018-02-28 | id_1 | loc_1 | x1_t2 | z1_t2 |
| 2 | 2018-03-31 | id_1 | NaN | x1_t3 | z1_t3 |
| 3 | 2018-01-31 | id_2 | loc_2 | x2_t1 | z2_t1 |
| 4 | 2018-02-28 | id_2 | loc_2 | x2_t2 | z2_t2 |
| 5 | 2018-03-31 | id_2 | NaN | x2_t3 | z2_t3 |
| 6 | 2018-01-31 | id_3 | loc_3 | x3_t1 | z3_t1 |
| 7 | 2018-02-28 | id_3 | loc_3 | x3_t2 | z3_t2 |
| 8 | 2018-03-31 | id_3 | NaN | x3_t3 | z3_t3 |

My dataframe is **not** ordered like the example. It is ordered by time.

Also, the panel is unbalances, meaning not all units show up in every period.

What I want to do is to fill the location values that are NaN with values that correspond to the same unit (i.e. id matches) from other periods, if the unit appears in some other period and has location information. Without messing up the other variables.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is the continuation of your code after dataframe (calling it **df** in below code) is created

```
id_loc_df = df[['id','location']].dropna().drop_duplicates().rename(columns={'location':'location_fill'})

df_updated = pd.merge(df, id_loc_df,left_on='id',right_on='id')

df_updated['location'] = np.where(df_updated['location'].isna(), df_updated['location_fill'], df_updated['location'])

df_updated.drop('location_fill', axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]